# Linux removing space in an echoed statement

Tags: linux, awk, echo, space

I am trying to create a script for a class and I am having a problem with my user count line. I cannot figure out how to move the 2 closer to the string. Below is what it looks like and my code is below that!

```
[root@testit /root]# ./syswatch
Free/Total Memory : 261/320  MB
Free/Total Swap : 259/259 MB
User count is at       2 


#!/bin/sh
#
# Syswatch       Shows a variety of different task based on my Linux System
#
# description:   This script will first check the percentage of the filesystem
#                being used. If the percentage is above ___, the root user will
#                be emailed. There will be 4 things echoed in this script. The
#                first thing being the amount of free/total memory being used,
#                second the amount of free/total swap space being used, the
#                third is the user count, and the last thing is the amount
#                of time that the system has been up for and the system load.

#Prints amount of Free/Total Memory and Swap

free -t -m | grep "Total" | awk '{ print "Free/Total Memory : "$4"/"$2"  MB";}'
free -t -m | grep "Swap" | awk '{ print "Free/Total Swap : "$4"/"$2" MB";}'

#Displays the user count for the system

echo "User count is at `who | wc -l`"


exit 0
```

Comment: I don't get that spacing from that running that echo line. What system is this?

Comment: That's not the way you'd write that script. You never need grep if you're using awk and you wouldn't call `free -t -m` twice, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the format well with `printf`

```
printf "User count is at %d\n" $(who | wc -l)
```

Note that I replaced the backticks with $().  This is primarily a style decision, but many (myself included) will argue that backticks are a horrible, horrible thing best relegated to the past.

Comment: In general, yes the command substitution should be quoted.  The `%d` should be changed to a `%s` as well, since `wc -l` might be changed to output something other than a single numeric value.  But if one relies on that output, neither the quotes nor the more general format string are necessary.

Comment: With `%d` printf throws away any leading spaces from the output of the command (but not trailing spaces). So for this specific instance it doesn't matter either way but the generally safer option is to quote (especially with `printf`s behavior of repeating the pattern to consume all arguments). Using `%s` would keep the spaces though and cause the original problem again (assuming one has that problem to begin with, which I don't).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `free` so I can't test it but try this:

```
free -t -m |
awk -v who="$(who)" '
/Total/ { printf "Free/Total Memory : %s/%s MB\n", $4, $2 }
/Swap/  { printf "Free/Total Swap : %s/%s MB\n", $4, $2 }
END { print "User count is at", gsub(/\n/,"",who) }
'
```